# Creating New Column in Pandas Data frame with For Loop Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to compare two columns (key.response and corr_answer) in a csv file using pandas and creating a new column "Correct_or_Not" that will contain a 1 in the cell if the key.response and corr_answer column are equal and a 0 if they are not. When I evaluate on their own outside of the loop they return the truth value I expect. The first part of the code is just me formatting the data to remove some brackets and apostrophes.

I tried using a for loop, but for some reason it puts a 0 in every column for 'Correct_or_Not".

```py
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('exptest.csv')
df['key.response'] = df['key.response'].str.replace(']','')
df['key.response'] = df['key.response'].str.replace('[','')
df['key.response'] = df['key.response'].str.replace("'",'')
df['corr_answer'] = df['corr_answer'].str.replace(']','')
df['corr_answer'] = df['corr_answer'].str.replace('[','')
df['corr_answer'] = df['corr_answer'].str.replace("'",'')

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['key.response'][i] == df['corr_answer'][i]:
        df['Correct_or_Not']=1
    else: 
        df['Correct_or_Not']=0

df.head()

  key.response corr_answer Correct_or_Not
0   1              1            0
1   2              2            0
2   1              2            0
```

Comment: the problem is `df['Correct_or_Not']=1` creates a new column of 1s from scratch each time (same with `df['Correct_or_Not']=0`)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the `Correct_or_Not` column all at once without the loop:

```py
df['Correct_or_Not'] = df['key.response'] == df['corr_answer']
```

and `df['Correct_or_Not'] = df['Correct_or_Not'].astype(int)` if you need the results as integers.

In your loop you forgot the index `[i]` when assigning the result. Like this the last row's result gets applied everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

```
df['Correct_or_not']=0
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        if df['key.response'][i]==df['corr_answer'][i]:
            df['Correct_or_not'][i]=1
```